# C selection sort fallacy, won't sort last 3 numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

So I've just started learning about C and algorithms and I've came across a problem in my selection sort algorithm. It gives me this as the output:

```
>10 
>12 
>13 
>16 
>23 
>25 
>42 
>60 
>50 
>52
```

The last three digits are out of order. Looking from my eyes they shouldn't be. Can you tell me guys what can be the problem here? Also my goal is to do this without any pointers and such, it's still a bit blurry from the last lecture and I know it can be done without it. I believe that this is more of a logical than memory error. Thank you everyone!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int max = 10;
    int a[max];
    //Makes unsorted array
    a[0] = 10;
    a[1] = 23;
    a[2] = 50;
    a[3] = 12;
    a[4] = 52;
    a[5] = 60;
    a[6] = 25;
    a[7] = 13;
    a[8] = 42;
    a[9] = 16;

/*
    SWAP MODEL
    printf("a[2] = %d \n", a[2]);
    int temp = a[3];
    a[3] = a[2];
    a[2] = temp;
    printf("a[2] = %d \n", a[2]);
*/    
    //Sorts array
    int n;
    int s = 0;
    int p = 0;
    for (n = 0; n < max-1; n++){
        int smallest = a[n];
        for(s = n + 1; s < max; s++){
            if(smallest > a[s]) {
                smallest = a[s];
                p = s;
            }
        }
        if  (n == 0 && p == 0) {
            int temp = a[n];
            a[n] = a[p];
            a[p] = temp;
        }
        else if (n > 0 && p == 0) {
            p = n;
            int temp = a[n];
            a[n] = a[p];
            a[p] = temp;
        }
        else {
            int temp = a[n];
            a[n] = a[p];
            a[p] = temp;
        }
    }

        //Checks if sorted
    for(int number = 0; number < 10; number++) {
        printf("%d \n", a[number]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1, for providing a compilable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int smallest = a[n];
```

Here you forget to initialize `p = n`, so your invariant `smallest == a[p]` is violated. With that addition it works.

Some more comments:

```
    if  (n == 0 && p == 0) {
        int temp = a[n];
        a[n] = a[p];
        a[p] = temp;
    }
    else if (n > 0 && p == 0) {
        p = n;
        int temp = a[n];
        a[n] = a[p];
        a[p] = temp;
    }
    else {
        int temp = a[n];
        a[n] = a[p];
        a[p] = temp;
    }
```

This whole construct is redundant, it just does the same thing in every case. You can replace it by an unconditional swap. My attempt at a cleaned up version:

```
for (int n = 0; n < max-1; n++){
    int p = n;
    int smallest = a[p];
    for (int s = n + 1; s < max; s++){
        if (smallest > a[s]) {
            smallest = a[s];
            p = s;
        }
    }
    int temp = a[n];
    a[n] = a[p];
    a[p] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Instead of replacing the whole cunstruct, I would test if `(p > n)` and then perform the swap or else do nothing.

Comment: @chaosmasttter: I would avoid the check because the code is simpler then and because performance is potentially even worse with the check because of branch-misprediction (that latter assumption I would have to verify with some timings though)

Comment: Oh my! It's always the little things. Thank you a lot for this. And the reason why I did all that checking is mainly to avoid confusion if the a[0] is in the same time the smallest, or similar. I did it when I started working on the algorithm and I totally just left it there without questioning it's functionality. I'll fix up the code a lil bit for aesthetics and it's ready to go. Thank you a lot with your help.